# What should the actioncable URL be set to under docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, actioncable

What should the action cable URL be set to when using Rails with Actioncable under Docker?

Normally it's something like

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3000/cable"
```

But that doesn't work. I've tried a few permutations but all I get is

```
Started GET "/cable" for 172.18.0.6 at 2016-11-22 17:49:37 +0000
Started GET "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 172.18.0.6 at 2016-11-22 17:49:37 +0000
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 172.18.0.6 at 2016-11-22 17:49:37 +0000
```

[My docker-compose.yml file is here](https://gist.github.com/simmogs/7ce5f9b59d6737b3d560a9c25bb689c8). I've tried using a separate cable image (commented out) without any luck. I don't get so far then, the app image and the cable image seem to be in conflict and one or both instances of puma just continuously restart. Fixing that would be a bonus.

Comment: Have you already looked at [this guide](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/dockerize-a-rails-5-postgres-redis-sidekiq-action-cable-app-with-docker-compose), looks like he's setting things up with ActionCable in its own container.

Answer (score 4):

If you run actioncable as standalone server in separate container, then you have to set allowed request origins for development environment:

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:28080"
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = %r{http://localhost.*}
```

Comment: this config also worked for me when ActionCable is included in the Rails container